# I want to invoke Object hashCode method through String object. How to do it?

Tags: java, string, object, hashcode, overriding

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {


    String s1 = "abc";


        //Here is invoking of overriding String hashCode method.
        System.out.println("hashCode value  "+s1.hashCode()); }
}
```

Instead of it,  I want to get non-overriding Object hashCode method. How do I get it?

Answer (score 15):

call `System.identityHashCode(s1)` instead.